# Height of rows being the same as width of rotated columns

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow, multicolumn

I have the following code, which creates a table by means of the *tabular* environment. I want the **height** of the first and second rows (Category and Subcat.1, Subcat.2) to be the same as the **width** of the first and second columns (the rotated ones). How can I do that? I've tried with *arraystretch*, but results seem approximated.

**EDIT TO CLARIFY THE QUESTION:** What I do want is the **height** between the line below Category 1 and the line below both Subcat. 1 and Subcat. 2 (**the blue arrow**) to be the same as the **width** between the vertical line on the right side of Category 2 and the line on the right side of both Subcat. 1 and Subcat. 2 (**the red arrow**). I mean: I am happy with the width. Now I want to make the height just the same, that is, make the blue arrow as high as wide is the red arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Category 1}                                                    \\ \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{Subcat. 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Subcat. 2}                     \\ \cline{3-4}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Subcat. 2}} & AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB \\ \cline{3-4}
        \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Category 2}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Subcat. 1}} & CCCCCCCCCC & DDDDDDDDDD \\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: '\vphantom{\rotatebox{90}{AAAAAAAAAA}}' in the box is a quick and dirty workaround. I hope there are better answers.

Comment: I think I don't understand your comment, @Huang_d

Comment: Meaning that within the box you add a height equivalent to the length of your text. This is done by using `rotatebox{90}{Your text}`  inside of `\vphantom`. The latter gives you a length equivalent to its contents (without printing them) and no horizontal width. It is not a good answer because it requires you to write your text twice, once as its printed, once invisible as the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few `@{}`, a few `\Vrule`s of baselineskip height, and put a few things into `\makebox`es of the same width as the height of `\Vrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\Vrule{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{\normalbaselineskip}}
%\def\Vrule{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.1pt}{\normalbaselineskip}}% USE THIS TO VERIFY
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Category 1}\\ 
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{\Vrule Subcat. 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Subcat. 2}\\
 \cline{3-4}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{\makebox[\normalbaselineskip]{%
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Vrule Subcat. 2}}} 
                & AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB \\ \cline{3-4}
        \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Category 2}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{\makebox[\normalbaselineskip]{%
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Vrule Subcat. 1}}} 
                & CCCCCCCCCC & DDDDDDDDDD \\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To verify it does what I says it does, uncomment the second `\Vrule` definition, which just makes it visible.  You will see that it exactly spans the two desired dimensions.

[image]

The OP asks to make the answer height adjustable, and that is no problem.  Change the dimensions of `\Vrule`, and make the `\makebox` width the same dimension.  EDITED to do the same for the Category 1/2 entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\Vrule{\rule[-2.5\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}
%\def\Vrule{\rule[-2.5\dp\strutbox]{.1pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}% USE THIS TO VERIFY
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}cc|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{\Vrule Category 1}\\ 
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{\Vrule Subcat. 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Subcat. 2}\\
 \cline{3-4}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{\makebox[2\normalbaselineskip]{%
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Vrule Subcat. 2}}} 
                & AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB \\ \cline{3-4}
        \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
          \makebox[2\baselineskip]{\Vrule Category 2}}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{\makebox[2\normalbaselineskip]{%
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Vrule Subcat. 1}}} 
                & CCCCCCCCCC & DDDDDDDDDD \\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One last point...if the `\Vrule` can *always* be guaranteed to have a larger footprint than `\strut`, then one can eliminate the `\makebox`es altogether, simplifying the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\Vrule{\rule[-2.5\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}
%\def\Vrule{\rule[-2.5\dp\strutbox]{.1pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}% USE THIS TO VERIFY
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}cc|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{\Vrule Category 1}\\ 
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{\Vrule Subcat. 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Subcat. 2}\\
 \cline{3-4}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{%
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Vrule Subcat. 2}}
                & AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB \\ \cline{3-4}
        \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
          \Vrule Category 2}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{|@{}c@{}|}{%
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Vrule Subcat. 1}} 
                & CCCCCCCCCC & DDDDDDDDDD \\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Steven. It is quite a comprehensive answer :) However, what I do want to change is the height (see the blue arrow in my question), not the width (the red arrow), which is what I think you change, don't you? Would it be difficult to adapt it to do so?

Comment: @Cromack No problem...done.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. Now, I see that I would like to make the space between Category 1 and the line below the same as the width between Category 2 and the vertical line, but I am afraid I didn't ask for that in the question... Would it require a similar approach? I am accepting your answer right now.

Comment: @Cromack Thank you.  I have edited to add that feature, as well.  I just had to add a `\Vrule` to Categories 1/2, place Category 2 in a `\makebox`, and add some `@{}` to column 1 specification.

Comment: @Cromack Note my final comment on the connection between `\Vrule` and the need or not for the `\makebox`.

Comment: Wow, that's just perfect. Thank you very much, Steven!

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding at  the top and bottom of rows with `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Category 1} \\ \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{Subcat. 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Subcat. 2} \\ \cline{3-4}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Subcat. 2}} & AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB \\ \cline{3-4}
        \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Category 2}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Subcat. 1}} & CCCCCCCCCC & DDDDDDDDDD \\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you type 3pt, and I can try with different lengths, but what's the exact length?

Comment: Yes, you can try different lengths. Do you mean what's the value of 3 pt?

Comment: What I mean is whether there is a way to know the exact length without trying different lengths?

Comment: Yes and no: as you can notice, the rotated text does not overflow in the above row, all you have to do is adding a small length so the two rotated texts have a  visible space between them. I'd say something like  2 to 4 pt are correct.

Comment: Oh, I think I must have asked the question wrongly... What I do want is the **height** between the line below Category 1 and the lines below both Subcat. 1 and Subcat. 2 to be the same as the **width** between the vertical line between Category 2 and the next line on the right. I mean: I am happy with that width. Now I want to make the height just the same. Must I edit my question?

Comment: I think you should indeed. Probably you can add (by trial an error= an invisible vertical rule with the relevant height and depth along with `Category 1`..

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick; specify the width of the second column explicitly, e. g. `p{.7cm}`, and add the same length as a vertical rule to the second row using the macro`\parbox{0cm}{\rule{0cm}{\dimexpr.7cm+2\tabcolsep}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\pad}[1]{\parbox{0cm}{\rule{0cm}{\dimexpr#1+2\tabcolsep}}}

    \begin{tabular}{c p{.7cm} c|c|}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Category 1}                                                      \\ \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{Subcat. 1\pad{.7cm}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Subcat. 2}             \\ \cline{3-4}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Subcat. 2~}} & AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB \\ \cline{3-4}
        \raisebox{1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Category 2}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Subcat. 1~}} & CCCCCCCCCC & DDDDDDDDDD \\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]