# How Middle Align a vertical oriented text in Tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabulary

[image: Table should be middle oriented]

This picture is a part of a table i am using, the terms subcases are vertically written but i cant center them vertically also in the next column terms like A, B are also not vertically centered. I made this table using tabulary package and i am also using this command

```
\begin{tabulary}{1\linewidth}{J J J J J J J J J J J J J}
```

to wrap my text in cells of table

Comment: This looks a lot like this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375058/height-of-rows-being-the-same-as-width-of-rotated-columns.  Is it a homework assignment, by chance?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i dont have the problem with the width of the cell but with the vertical align of text like the one use can do in excel {top, middle, bottom alignment}

Comment: It will help people help you, if you edit your question to provide a short compiling code of what you did that produces the undesirable result.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full, yet minimal, compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375719/how-to-middle-align-a-vertical-oriented-text-in-tables

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375719/how-to-middle-align-a-vertical-oriented-text-in-tables