# How to Middle Align a vertical oriented text in Tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabulary

[image: Text should be vertically aligned]

This picture is a part of a table i am using, the terms subcases are vertically written but i cant center them vertically also in the next columns terms like A, B, etc are also not vertically centered. I made this table using tabulary package a. My code is

```
\begin{table}[H]

\centering

\caption{Saturation Table}

\label{tab:5}%

\begin{tabulary}{1\linewidth}{J J J J J J J J J J J J J}

\toprule

& \textbf{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}} & \textbf{Step 0} & \textbf{Step 1} & \textbf{Step 2} & \textbf{Step 3} & \textbf{Step 4} & \textbf{Step 5} & \textbf{Step 6} & \textbf{Step 7} & \textbf{Step 8} & \textbf{Step 9} \\

\midrule

\multirow{4}[4]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Subcase A}\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{A}} & \textbf{No} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \textbf{6} & & & & \\[1mm]

& & \textbf{Maximum Saturation {(\%)}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & \textbf{5} & & & & \\

\cmidrule{2-13} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{B}} & \textbf{No} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \textbf{8} & & \\[1mm]

& & \textbf{Maximum Saturation {(\%)}} & 6 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 19 & \textbf{8} & & \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}%

\end{table}%
```

Comment: Hi @Shaggi3, I think that if you provide the packages needed to runn your code we can help you much easier

Comment: @koleygr These are all the packages im using in the document of the table
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
\usepackage{graphicx}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{tabulary} \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{multicol} \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} \usepackage{cite} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan, }

\title{TestLE}
\author{Konstantinos Leledakis}
\date{June 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[H]

\centering

\caption{Saturation Table}

\label{tab:5}%
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabulary}{1.5\linewidth}{J J J J J J J J J J J J J}

\toprule

& \textbf{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}} & \textbf{Step 0} & \textbf{Step 1} & \textbf{Step 2} & \textbf{Step 3} & \textbf{Step 4} & \textbf{Step 5} & \textbf{Step 6} & \textbf{Step 7} & \textbf{Step 8} & \textbf{Step 9} \\

\midrule

\multirow{6}[6]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Subcase A}}} & 
\multirow{3}[3]{*}{\textbf{A}} & \textbf{No} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \textbf{6} & & & & \\[1mm]

& & \textbf{Maximum Saturation {(\%)}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & \textbf{5} & & & & \\

\cmidrule{2-13} & \multirow{3}[3]{*}{\textbf{B}} & \textbf{No} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \textbf{8} & & \\[1mm]

& & \textbf{Maximum Saturation {(\%)}} & 6 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 19 & \textbf{8} & & \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}%
}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

It seems that the extra rows count as rows in this table and you can not ignore them in multirow count

Another answer is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{tabulary} \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{multicol} \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} \usepackage{cite} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan, }


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\date{June 2017}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[H]

\centering

\caption{Saturation Table}

\label{tab:5}%
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabulary}{1.5\linewidth}{J c C{4.7cm} *{10}{C{1.5cm}}}

\toprule

& \textbf{Method} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}} & \textbf{Step 0} & \textbf{Step 1} & \textbf{Step 2} & \textbf{Step 3} & \textbf{Step 4} & \textbf{Step 5} & \textbf{Step 6} & \textbf{Step 7} & \textbf{Step 8} & \textbf{Step 9} \\

\midrule

\multirow{4}[4]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Subcase A}}} & 
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{A}} & \textbf{No} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \textbf{6} & & & & \\[1mm]

& & \textbf{Maximum Saturation {(\%)}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & \textbf{5} & & & & \\

\cmidrule{2-13} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{B}} & \textbf{No} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \textbf{8} & & \\[1mm]

& & \textbf{Maximum Saturation {(\%)}} & 6 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 19 & \textbf{8} & & \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}%
}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

with the following result (but it would be nice to be in landscape mode):

[image]

Comment: I saw it doesn't work... looking to fix it!

Comment: Updated! I think this is what you want

Comment: You are welcome... but still don't know which solution is your choice...  You can improve it by choosing the desired length in C type columns

Comment: first one is better because my real values are longer then 1, 2 and 3 due to which the table rows become wider when table width is kept fixed that extra row is because of this but still thanks alot

Comment: Ok, I would try to fix the table in my specific taste using both answers... The C column helps enough... also it would be better this kind of column in your "Steps"... try it